# Different USE flags for a binary package server and host

Tags: compiling, package-management, gentoo

I have 2 systems that both run Gentoo. I want to use one to build binary packages for the other and have been following [this wiki article](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Binary_package_guide). One problem I have is that I have different use flags for my 2 systems.

As an example, I have vim installed on both my package server and package host. My package server has the USE flag `gpm`, but my build host has `-gpm`. If I use `quickpkg` and move vim from my package server to my package host, I get the error `./vim: error while loading shared libraries: libgpm.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`, which means that the host is missing gpm support.

I'm not too familiar with Gentoo yet, so I'm not sure how I can resolve this. I've tried Googling everything I can think of, but I haven't found anything that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my situation, I found the solution to be [distcc](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Distcc), which eyoung100 suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

No robust solution yet.

https://bugs.gentoo.org/150031

La la la la la (30 characters yet?)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the USE-flag for VIM using this commands:

```
sudo echo ">=app-editors/vim-7.4.273 gpm" >> /etc/portage/package.use 
sudo emerge -av vim
```

or you could set the gpm flag globally in /etc/portage/make.conf and ad it in the line USE

```
USE="gpm <a bunch of other use flags>"
```

and after this update the system with the new USE-flag

```
sudo emerge -Nav @world
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Sabayon Linux](http://www.sabayon.org/), a child of Gentoo.  It uses pre-compiled packages, a.k.a binaries stored in repos, that are remote.  What actually happens is that maintainers configure the package using predetermined USE Flags, and then compile the package with portage.  Then using the Sabayon Binary Package Manager, [Entropy](https://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=Entropy), the maintainers upload the compiled package to a Sabayon repo, and it becomes "the binary."

It's not quite what you're looking for, but it's mighty close, and would eliminate the need for a buildhost.

Comment: This is not a bad idea as long as the build host and build server have similar uses. However, my situation is a little more tricky. My 2 build clients happen to be very minimal servers (no X, no alsa, one has no syslog, etc) for different purposes, and my build server is going to be my general-use desktop. I need to be in charge how the packages are compiled on a per-host basis to avoid installing unecessary dependencies on either of my servers.

Comment: The [Saybyon Minimal ISO](http://www.sabayon.org/latest) comes with only fbdev IIRC.  It's been awhile since I've been in a switching mood.  If you still can't make that fit have you looked at [distcc](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Distcc)??  The only way I can think to control USE Flags is to compile on each machine independently, then create your own binary package tree on a server and tell portage to use the binary tree on your server and not a remote tree

Comment: DistCC does exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: @MisterDood Do I need to update my answer for you to accept it?

Comment: I actually don't want you to change your answer because it's a perfectly valid solution to someone else who has this problem under different circumstances, and asking you to change your valid answer to what I've already posted as my personal solution just doesn't sound right to me. The point of the Stack Exchange network is to provide multiple solutions to a problem so that everyone can find something that works for them and upvote it, not just me.